# Algorithm for partitioning graph vertices into sets of indistinguishable vertices in unlabeled graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring, automorphism-group

Given a graph G=(V,E) I'd like to group its vertices into sets, so that indistinguishable vertices go in the same set and vertices that are structurally different go into different sets.
Consider the following example:

[image: Graph colouring example]

With this example I'd like to get to exactly these four sets, however I don't know how to get there. If I use the adjacency matrix of the graph the four vertices in set 1 and 2 all end up in a different set. And if I only look at the degrees, vertices from set 1 and 4 end up in the same set. I guess that if I get the same result from my two methods the result is correct, however that only works for a small subset of graphs and I'm looking for a general approach that works for all graphs (or at least connected graphs).

In practice I could use the naive approach of just looking at all possible labelings of my graph and see if I get the same adjacency matrix for a different labeling and based on that infer equivalent vertices. My graphs aren't even that big, approx. 10-12 nodes, but as I have to do this for a large number of graphs I hope there is a more efficient approach.

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to the graph isomorphism problem, since you're trying to get a partial description of the automorphism group of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this that's better than brute force, because this is as hard as graph isomorphism. (If you want to know whether $G \cong H$ and have this partitioning algorithm, you can run it on the disjoint union of $G$ and $H$, and check if any vertex in $G$ is in the same set as any vertex in $H$.)

For very small graphs, it might be easiest to use brute force. For larger graphs, you probably want to use existing software rather than write your own algorithm. In particular...

---

...this can be done with [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/). The labeling you are looking for is the array of the orbits of the automorphism group. The manual goes into the details of how to find it, but here is a summary:

- To do this for one graph at a time, you could use the dreadnaut interface. You'll need the `n=# g` command to enter the graph, the `x` command to run nauty, and the `O` command to get the orbits.
- In a C program, you can call `densenauty` with a whole bunch of parameters, one of which (`int* orbits`) will contain the orbits after nauty is called.

In the C program, and I believe in dreadnaut as well, the $k$ orbits will not be labeled $1$ through $k$; rather, each vertex in an orbit will be labeled with the number of the first vertex in that orbit.

---

... in Mathematica, you can do this with `GroupOrbits[GraphAutomorphismGroup[graph]]`. This will not be as efficient as nauty or other graph isomorphism software for large graphs.

---

... [igraph](https://igraph.org/) is a graph algorithm library with interfaces in several languages. I've only ever used it in Mathematica, where you could improve on the solution above (for large graphs) with `GroupOrbits[IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[graph]]` after loading IGraph. But I assume you can do the equivalent in R, Python, and C++ just as easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I'm missing a lot of knowledge on these topics. This really helps.